# jQuery toggle button not working .on('click')

Tags: javascript, jquery, toggleclass, togglebutton

this is a script i found here, which i changed from .live to .on

I have an anchor with a class login attached, the logout will open a form using jquery, and change the text and class of the current anchor, to logout.

```
<li><a href="javascript:void(0)" class="login">Login</a></li>
```

When clicked it works all fine, everything is changed, but when i click on that anchor again it will not active to logout function. I know it has something to do with jquery or dom needing to refresh itself, but i don't know how to make it work?

```
function onSignOutClicked() {
    // Convert the clicked button into a sign-in button
    $(this)
        .attr('class', 'login')
        .attr('title', 'Login')
        .text('Sign in');
}

function onSignInClicked() {
    // Convert the clicked button into a sign-out button
    $(this)
        .attr('class', 'logout')
        .attr('title', 'Logout')
        .text('Sign out');
}

$('.logout').on("click", onSignOutClicked);
$('.login').on("click", onSignInClicked);
```

i have also written my own one below, which is an alternative method, but here the problem is that the old class is still working when it was changed.

```
$(".sendLoginForm").click(function(){
    $("#loginErr").html("");
    $(".sendLoginForm").css({"color":"#ff3019"});
    $(".sendLoginForm").spin("small", "#FFF");                          
    $.ajax({  
        type: "POST",  
        url: "../_/login.php",  
        data: $("#loginForm").serialize(),  
        dataType: "json",  
        success: function(data){
            if (data.err){
                $("#loginErr").html(data.err);
            }else{
                //$(".openLoginForm").closest('li').remove();
                //$(".ulNavigator").append('<li><a href="javascript:void(0)" class="logout">Logout</a></li>');
                //$('.openLoginForm').toggleClass('.logout')
                //$(".openLoginForm").removeClass('.openLoginForm').addClass('logout');
                $(".openLoginForm").toggleClass('openLoginForm logout');
                $('.login').fadeOut("fast");
                $(".success").html(data.success);
                $('.success').fadeIn("fast");
                $('#loginForm')[0].reset();
                setTimeout(function() {
                      $('.success').fadeOut("fast");
                }, 3000);
                }
            $(".sendLoginForm").spin(false);
            $(".sendLoginForm").css({"color":"#FFF"});
        }                       
    });
    return false;
});

$(document).on("click", ".logout", function(){
    $.ajax({  
        type: "POST",  
        url: "../_/logout.php",  
        data: {logout : "kick"},  
        dataType: "json",  
        success: function(data){
            if (data.success){
                $(".success").html(data.success);
                $(".success").fadeIn("fast");
                setTimeout(function() {
                      $('.success').fadeOut("fast");
                }, 3000);
            }
        }                   
    }); 

});
```

Any help on ether method would be much appreciated, thank you.

Comment: Instead of `javascript:void(0)`, why not simply use `preventDefault()` within the function?

Comment: Thanks Sparky, didn't know that would do the same, i did use preventDefault on form submitions, i need to study more haha. Kudos

Comment: It's not exactly the same, but a `href="#"` in conjunction with a proper `preventDefault()` in the click handler would be a nicer implementation, IMO.  `.click(function(e){ e.preventDefault(); ...`

Comment: ok, thanks for your opinion Sparky!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Changing the class of an element won't change what events are bound to it. Event Delegation would be closer to what you want:

```
$(document).on('click','.logout',onSignOutClicked);
$(document).on('click','.login',onSignInClicked);
```

Additionally, don't change the class of an element using .attr, instead use .addClass(), .removeClass, and/or .toggleClass.

```
$(this).addClass("logout").removeClass("login")
```

with that in mind, you can simplify the whole process with:

```
$(".login,.logout").on("click",function(){
    var $this = $(this);
    $this.toggleClass("login logout");
    if ( $this.is(".login") ) {
        $this.attr("title","Login");
    }
    else {
        $this.attr("title","Logout");
    }    
});
```

and you can make it smaller with:

```
$(".login,.logout").on("click",function(){
    var $this = $(this);
    $this.toggleClass("login logout");
    $this.attr("title", $this.is(".login") ? "Login" : "Logout");
});
```

Comment: Thanks Kevin B, that worked, and thank you for the explanation, i'm now starting to understand the allocation of an even handler to what class it has changed to.

Answer (score 0):

you should do:

```
 function onSignOutClicked() {
        // Convert the clicked button into a sign-in button
        $(this)
            .attr('class', 'login')
            .attr('title', 'Login')
            .text('Sign in');
    }

    function onSignInClicked() {
        // Convert the clicked button into a sign-out button
        $(this)
            .attr('class', 'logout')
            .attr('title', 'Logout')
            .text('Sign out');
    }

    $('.logout').on("click", function(){ 
    onSignOutClicked();
    });
    $('.login').on("click", function(){ 
    onSignInClicked();
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

For all who want to see my result, this is a working example of what i wanted to do with the help of Kevin B.

Thank you all

```
$(".login,.logout").on("click",function(){
    var $this = $(this);
    if ( $this.is(".login") ) {
        $(".loginFormBox").fadeIn("fast");      
    }
    else {
        $this.text("Login");
        $this.toggleClass("login logout");
        $.ajax({  
        type: "POST",  
        url: "../_/logout.php",  
        data: {logout : "kick"},  
        dataType: "json",  
        success: function(data){
            if (data.success){
                $(".success").html(data.success);
                $(".success").fadeIn("fast");
                setTimeout(function() {
                      $('.success').fadeOut("fast");
                }, 3000);
            }
        }                   
        }); 
    }    
});

$(".sendLoginForm").click(function(){
    $("#loginErr").html("");
    $(".sendLoginForm").css({"color":"#ff3019"});
    $(".sendLoginForm").spin("small", "#FFF");                          
    $.ajax({  
        type: "POST",  
        url: "../_/login.php",  
        data: $("#loginForm").serialize(),  
        dataType: "json",  
        success: function(data){
            if (data.err){
                $("#loginErr").html(data.err);
            }else{
                $(".login").toggleClass("login logout");
                $(".logout").text("Logout");
                $('.loginFormBox').fadeOut("fast");
                $(".success").html(data.success);
                $('.success').fadeIn("fast");
                $('#loginForm')[0].reset();
                setTimeout(function() {
                      $('.success').fadeOut("fast");
                }, 3000);
                }
            $(".sendLoginForm").spin(false);
            $(".sendLoginForm").css({"color":"#FFF"});
        }                       
    });
    return false;
});
```